# nested resolvers in Ariadne

Tags: python, django, django-models, ariadne-graphql

When querying for list of products I need to show the product information along with variation. I mean i want products query to return something like this

```
{
  "data": {
    "product": {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Polo Shirt",
      "productType": {
        "name": "clothing"
      },
      "category": {
        "name": "Men's"
      },
      "variants": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "S",
          "variant": [
            {
              "attribute": {
                "name": "Size"
              },
              "values": [
                {
                  "name": "S"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "XL",
          "attributes": [
            {
              "attribute": {
                "name": "Size"
              },
              "values": [
                {
                  "name": "XL"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For such result, I have my schema for products as following

```
type Query {
    products: [Product]
}

type Product implements Node {
    id: ID
    productType: ProductType!
    name: String!
    slug: String!
    description: String!
    category: Category!
    attributes: [SelectedAttribute]
    variants: [ProductVariant]
    articleNumber: String
    barcode: String
}

type SelectedAttribute {
    attribute: Attribute
    values: [AttributeValue]
}

type Attribute implements Node {
    id: ID
    name: String
}

type AttributeValue implements Node {
    id: ID
    name: String
}

type ProductVariant implements Node {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  sku: String!
  product: Product!
  variant: [VariantAttributes]
}

type VariantAttributes {
    attribute: Attribute
    values: VariantAttribute
}

type VariantAttribute implements Node {
    id: ID
    name: String
    slug: String
    value: String
}
```

The model is

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ProductType, related_name="products", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        related_name="products",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Attribute(ModelWithMetadata):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True, allow_unicode=True)
    has_variants = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class AttributeValue(SortableModel):
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(Attribute, related_name="values", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True, allow_unicode=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class ProductAttribute(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(Attribute, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.attribute.name

class VariantAttribute(models.Model):
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(Attribute, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True, allow_unicode=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value

class ProductVariant(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="variants")
    variant = models.ManyToManyField(VariantAttribute, related_name="productvariants")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

My resolver is following

```
query = QueryType()
mutation = MutationType()
product = ObjectType('Product')
product_variant = ObjectType('ProductVariant')

@query.field('products')
@convert_kwargs_to_snake_case
def resolve_products(obj, info, **args):
    products = models.Product.objects.all()
    return products

@product.field('variants')
def resolve_product_variants(obj, info):
    return models.ProductVariant.objects.filter(product=obj)

@product_variant.field('variant')
def resolve_attributes_of_product_variants(obj, info):
    variant_attrs = models.Attribute.objects.filter(has_variants=True, productattribute__product=obj)
    variant_attr_values = models.VariantAttribute.objects.none()
    for attr in variant_attrs:
        variant_attr_values |= models.VariantAttribute.objects.filter(attribute=attr)
    print('variant_attrs', variant_attrs)
    print('variant_attr_values', variant_attr_values)
    return [
        {
            'attribute': variant_attrs,
            'values': variant_attr_values
        }
    ]
```

I have no idea how to resolve variants property. Can anyone help me at this, please?